# How to load balance Azure Cloud Service TCP/UDP endpoint between regions?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-load-balancer

Currently my Azure Cloud Service has a role that is UDP/TCP server. Role has already multiple instances and has static IP via Azure Reserved IP. The clients don't have DNS capability and can only connect via IP address only.

My goal is to have the Cloud Service geo-redundant in active/active fashion. I was hoping Azure load balancer would do the trick but it appears to work only with VMs and not geo-redundant Cloud Services.

How do I accomplish this?

Yes, I have read about "Internet facing load balancer for cloud services" ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-get-started-internet-classic-cloud)) but I need to load balance UDP/TCP traffic between Cloud Services in different regions (multiple deployments) and not just between instances in same deployment.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose to load balance the service in different regions, you can accomplish that with Azure Traffic Manager instead of Load Balancer, maybe it's more appropriate for your purpose.

For more details about Azure Traffic Manager, see [What is Traffic Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-overview).

Comment: "Azure Traffic Manager is a DNS-based traffic load balancer." My client devices don't have DNS capability and can connect via IP address only.

Comment: @LucasM But the traffic manager has the endpoint such as Cloud service, you can choose it.